# python flask-restful cannot get app access in resource class

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

Here is the sample code from [flask-restful doc](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api)

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful

app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)

class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The `HelloWorld` class is in the same python file, say `app.py`, it works.

Now I am going to put the `HelloWorld` class to a separate class file, like following layout:

```
app
app/__init__.py # hold above code except the HelloWorld class.
app/resource
app/resource/__init__.py # empty
app/resource/HelloWorld.py # hold the above HelloWorld class.
```

The `app/__init__.py` contains :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful
from resource.HelloWorld import HelloWorld

app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the `HelloWorld.py` is:

```
from flask.ext import restful
from app import app

class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

Running the app would get exception:

```
ImportError: No module named app on HelloWorld.py
```

I do need to access app to read some information like `app.config`, how can i make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a circular import; when the line `from resource.HelloWorld import HelloWorld` executes, `app` has not yet been assigned to, so in `Helloworld.py` the line `from app import app` fails.

Either import `HelloWorld` later:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful

app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)

from resource.HelloWorld import HelloWorld
api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

or import just the `app` module in `HelloWorld.py`:

```
from flask.ext import restful
import app

class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}
```

and refer to `app.app` within a function or method called at a later time.