# Getting the database connection from application context with Flask-Restful

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have an app using Flask-Restful and I don't know how to get the database connection info from the application context.

Here is what I have so far:

**app.py:**

```
....
from flask.ext.restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DATABASE'] = 'my.db'
api = Api(app) 
api.add_resource(Foo, '/')
```

**foo.py**

```
...
from flask.ext.restful import Resource

class Foo(Resource):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = get_db()
    def post(self):
        do_stuff_with_db()
```

I'd like the get_db method to look something like:

```
def get_db():
    return database.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
```

The problem is in order to get app.config into foo.py, I create a circular reference. Is there a clean, and hopefully idomatic way to get this?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707589/python-flask-restful-cannot-get-app-access-in-resource-class?rq=1), but the solution given doesn't actually resolve the circular import problem.

Comment: The link you shared appears to point to the wrong place.

Comment: Fixed the link, thanks @dirn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for my project I use this kind of structure:

### application/__init__.py

```
...
app = Flask(__name__)
...
db  = SQLAlchemy(app) #because I use sqlalchemy
...
import application.core
```

### application/core.py

```
from application.api import resource
...
# api definition
```

### application/api/resource.py

```
from application import db
...
db.doWhatEverYouWant()
...
```

It's certainly not perfect but I don't have such kind of circular import problems.