# Flask-RESTful Project Structure

Tags: python, sqlite, rest, flask, flask-restful

Here is what I'm working with:

```
/myproject
    README.md
    runserver.py
    /myproject
        __init__.py
        api.py
        /resources
            __init__.py
            foo.py
            bar.py
        /common
            __init__.py
            db.py
    /tests
        test_myproject.py
```

Nothing special here. Most of this can be found on the [Intermediate Usage](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intermediate-usage.html) page in the Flask-RESTful User's Guide.

My concern is with circular imports...

**api.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__)

from myproject.resources.foo import Foo
from myproject.resources.bar import Bar

api = Api(app)

api.add_resource(Foo, '/Foo', '/Foo/<str:id>')
api.add_resource(Bar, '/Bar', '/Bar/<str:id>')
```

**foo.py**

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from myproject.common.db import query_db


class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass
    def post(self):
        pass
```

**db.py**

```
from flask import g
import sqlite3
from myproject.api import app


def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
        db.row_factory = make_dicts
    return db


def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

Clearly, I have introduced a circular import into my project:

```
api.py -> foo.py -> db.py -> api.py
```

This isn't a *big* problem as long as I instantiate the Flask application object before I import my resources (which I do). A similar pattern is discussed [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) (see the Circular Imports section at the bottom of the page).

**My question...**

Is this a good way to structure a Flask-RESTful project?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387077/getting-the-database-connection-from-application-context-with-flask-restful) is the closest SO question on this topic that I could find. I was not satisfied with the answer provided because I don't want to keep my database functions in the top level `__init__.py` file (or in `api.py` - where the routes belong).

Here are several other similar SO questions, but they are dealing with import errors (which I am not):

[Structure Flask-Restful API to use SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999931/structure-flask-restful-api-to-use-sqlalchemy)

[Error importing models when trying to run app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470565/error-importing-models-when-trying-to-run-app)

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is largely opinion based, I'm going to suggest what I think would be a better solution :)

Instead of importing `myproject.api.app` in `db.py`, I would create my own module level global variable in `db.py` to store database configuration:

**db.py**

```
from flask import g
import sqlite3

_db_config = None # Holds database config

def init(app):
    """ Function must be called to initalize this module """
    global _db_config
    global close_connection
    _db_config = app.config['DATABASE']
    # Manually apply @app.teardown_appcontext decorator
    close_connection = app.teardown_appcontext(close_connection)


def _db_connect():
    if _db_config is None:
        raise Exception('Call init first') # or whatever error you want
    return sqlite3.connect(_db_config)


def get_db():
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = _db_connect()
        db.row_factory = make_dicts
    return db

....

def close_connection(exception):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is not None:
        db.commit()
        db.close()
```

Then in `api.py` initialize db by calling `myproject.common.db.init()`

**api.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from myproject.common import db

app = Flask(__name__)
db.init(app)

....
```

This way `db.py` no longer has a dependency on `api.py`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like your solution, however, `db.py` would still have a dependency on `api.py`. See the `close_connection` function with the `@app.teardown_appcontext` decorator.

Comment: That can be easily fixed if you don't mind manually applying the decorator :). See my edit above.

Comment: First, I think you need to declare `close_connection` as global in your `init` function or else Python will treat it as a local variable. Second, when I try this approach I get the following error: `ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.`

Comment: Right. Corrected that. Can you trace the location of the `ProgrammingError`?

Comment: Hey what about runserver.py ?

Comment: wow so many different variation. im confused which one is the correct structure of flask