# Having trouble structuring my Flask-Restful App, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

So I'm trying to graduate from the single file application and organize my flask app for scalability. However, I can't even get past running the server... I tried duplicating exact stackoverflow questions that have had similar troubles before, but no luck, i.e. [Structure Flask-Restful API to use SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999931/structure-flask-restful-api-to-use-sqlalchemy), [python flask-restful cannot get app access in resource class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21707589/python-flask-restful-cannot-get-app-access-in-resource-class).

I got a regular flask app to work following this structure: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/, however, I have a restful extension that I'm trying to structure, and it's not working.

The error I am getting is:

```
from yourapplication.resources.foo import Foo
ImportError: No module named resources.foo
```

My directory structure is:

```
/myapp
  runserver.py
  /venv
  /yourapplication
    init.py
    api.py
    /resources
      foo.py
```

In runserver.py, I have:

```
from yourapplication import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

For **init**.py, I have:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import yourapplication.api
```

lastly, for foo.py, I have:

```
from flask_restful import Resource


class Foo(Resource):
    def get(self):
        pass
    def post(self):
        pass
```

It's so simple, yet I can't get it to work. I followed, http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/, and it works for a regular flask app, but not yet found luck structuring restful extension flask apps, which is what I'm dealing with. Please help guys!

Comment: Is `__init__.py` not `init.py`. You have tot put an `__init__.py` file in the `resources` folder too.

Comment: What in the heck. The __init__.py works. Wow. Why is that? That's so strange, I thought those were optional...